# TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working through a basic MEAN tutorial, and I am already hitting a wall. Getting 'TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function' error

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "http-server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4"
  }
}


//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function (res, req) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(1337);
console.log('Visit me at http://localhost:1337');
```

Comment: app.get('/', function (req, res) {

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please re-arrange callback arguments:

```
function(req,res){}
```

Example:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake here 
app.get('/', function (res, req) 
just write 
app.get('*', function(req, res)
and it will work